# What is unclear about meta question 1098?

Tags: discussion, support

[This meta question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1098/67) is put on hold for being unclear.

I do not understand how it is unclear.

I want to know what aspect is unclear about this question so that I can improve it.

I do not want to add any example to this question because based on my past experiences most probably it will be hijacked to discuss about that specific example to if it is on-topic on this site or not. so I want to my question be focused on a scenario without any example. in fact this scenario is irrelevant of having or not having any example.

But I am ready to add any needed explanation to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems with that question

1. It is too long (unnecessarily). It can be easily curtailed with out loosing any value in the question itself.
2. It does not contain any example/use case which the user can consider while answering the question.
3. In the question, you are putting a kind of answer/suggestion as well. That is basically has making the question too long.
4. Some of the things you pointed out in the question can be part of a separate question itself.

So in short I would advice to please make the question only one paragraph, on one topic with a use case. Avoid any suggestion in the question itself (at least in this one). That way the question will be much more focused and clear.

Comment: I agree with the problems you mentioned and god willing will resolve them. but which of them make it unclear? it is put on hold for being unclear. with all of these problems my question still can be clear.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala not having a valid use case + too long of text.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala The reader of the question and not supposed to speculate/guess as to what the question is. If the find themselves doing that it's unclear. [something you just can't understand. And your response after reading it two or three times is "Ok. So what's the question?". Vote to close. Or flag.](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/942/3487)

Comment: @BleedingFingers is my question really of this case?